# Uncaught error: function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a really simple code that retrieves share counts from Facebook, but I'm getting an error that function sndFBcount is now defined.

Here's the code:

```
$.getScript( 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=' + encodeURIComponent( "SELECT total_count, url FROM link_stat WHERE url='" + sndSharingURL + "'" ) + '&format=json&callback=sndFBcount' );
function sndFBcount(data) {
    if ( 'undefined' != typeof data.count && ( data.count * 1 ) > 0 ) {
         alert(data.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to move the function before ajax call.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that already and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: The function must be globally defined. If `sndFBcount` is nested inside another function, it'll fail,.

Comment: @bingjie2680: That would make no difference for two reasons. First is that function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of their enclosing variable scope. Second is that `$getScript` is asynchronous, so all synchronous code that comes after the call will always complete before the async callback is invoked.

Comment: The code above was in a function. I took my function outside and it worked. It also work by declaring it `sndFBcount = function(data)` inside that function.

Thanks !

Comment: Your `sndFBcount = func...` creates an implicit global. This is often considered bad form, and is prohibited in JavaScript's strict mode. If you want to define it globally from that position, make it a property of `window`, so `window.sndFBCount = func...`. This explicitly makes it a global variable.